# Flutter: How to prevent exception from getting printed in debug console?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using try catch for error handling and displaying widget if there is error. This works but the exception still prints in the debug console, the exception in this case is `IOException`, how to prevent this exception from getting printed in console?

```
try {
    PDFDocument pdfDocument = await PDFDocument.fromURL(pdfUrl);
    Navigator.of(context).push(
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (ctx) =>
            DisplayPdf(pdfDocument),
      ),
    );
} catch (error) {
    showDialog(...);
}
```

The code of the `fromURL` function from the pdf package I am using:

```
static Future<PDFDocument> fromURL(String url) async {
    // Download into cache
    File f = await DefaultCacheManager().getSingleFile(url);
    PDFDocument document = PDFDocument();
    document._filePath = f.path;
    try {
      var pageCount =
          await _channel.invokeMethod('getNumberOfPages', {'filePath': f.path});
      document.count = document.count = int.parse(pageCount);
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception('Error reading PDF!');
    }
    return document;
  }
```

Comment: Add code which throws exception.

Comment: @VirenVVarasadiya Have updated the question with code.

Comment: Are you sure that exception is actually coming from this try catch block ?

Comment: @SwapnilNakade Yes

Comment: My guess is that something in `PDFDocument` or `DisplayPDF` internally catches the exception, prints a message to the console, and rethrows.  If so, there likely is nothing you can do (unless your PDF plugin provides some mechanism for configuring that behavior).  I suppose you could try to temporarily override `debugPrint`, but that's a gross hack, and there's no guarantee that the PDF plugin uses `debugPrint`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I have added the code of the pdf package I am using, internally it catches and throws an exception.